# How to solve SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^ in JSON at position error?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

I am receiving a dynamic data string from the python kernel, (however, it's an object but the python kernel can only send it as a sting due to the limitation of the python backend that cant be changed due to a third-party package), below is the console.log output.

```
[{"model_class": "DataToolParameter", "name": "input_file", "argument": null, "type": "data", "label": "VCF/BCF Data", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": true, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": null, "extensions": ["vcf", "vcf_bgzip", "bcf"], "edam": {"edam_formats": ["format_3016", "format_3016", "format_3020"], "edam_data": ["data_0006", "data_0006", "data_3498"]}, "multiple": false, "options": {"hda": [], "hdca": []}, "default_value": null, "text_value": "No dataset."}, {"model_class": "Section", "name": "sec_required", "type": "section", "title": "Required References", "help": null, "expanded": true, "inputs": [{"model_class": "Conditional", "name": "reference_source", "type": "conditional", "cases": [{"model_class": "ConditionalWhen", "value": "cached", "inputs": [{"model_class": "SelectToolParameter", "name": "fasta_ref", "argument": null, "type": "select", "label": "Reference genome", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": true, "value": null, "options": [], "display": null, "multiple": false, "textable": false, "default_value": null, "text_value": "None"}]}, {"model_class": "ConditionalWhen", "value": "history", "inputs": [{"model_class": "DataToolParameter", "name": "fasta_ref", "argument": null, "type": "data", "label": "Reference genome", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": true, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": {"values": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "src": "hda"}]}, "extensions": ["fasta"], "edam": {"edam_formats": ["format_1929"], "edam_data": ["data_2044"]}, "multiple": false, "options": {"hda": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "hid": 11, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: multiz100way (chrX:15,578,261-15,621,068) (as fasta)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "33d7a2c94fd36485", "hid": 9, "name": "non_ACPs.fasta", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "47f5e6f7acd01631", "hid": 3, "name": "Extract MAF blocks on data 2 (as fasta)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "695fd3e24b533dbc", "hid": 2, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: multiz100way (chrX:15,560,138-15,602,945) (as fasta)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}], "hdca": []}, "default_value": {"values": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "src": "hda"}]}, "text_value": "No dataset."}]}], "test_param": {"model_class": "SelectToolParameter", "name": "reference_source_selector", "argument": null, "type": "select", "label": "Choose the source for the reference genome", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": true, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "cached", "options": [["Use a built-in genome", "cached", false], ["Use a genome from the history", "history", false]], "display": null, "multiple": false, "textable": false, "text_value": "Use a built-in genome"}}, {"model_class": "DataToolParameter", "name": "gff_annot", "argument": null, "type": "data", "label": "GFF3 annotation file", "help": "From Ensembl:  ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_gff3/", "refresh_on_change": true, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": null, "extensions": ["gff3"], "edam": {"edam_formats": ["format_1975"], "edam_data": ["data_1255"]}, "multiple": false, "options": {"hda": [], "hdca": []}, "default_value": null, "text_value": "No dataset."}]}, {"model_class": "Section", "name": "sec_csq_opts", "type": "section", "title": "CSQ Options", "help": null, "expanded": true, "inputs": [{"model_class": "IntegerToolParameter", "name": "ncsq", "argument": null, "type": "integer", "label": "maximum number of consequences to consider per site", "help": "-ncsq 16", "refresh_on_change": false, "min": 1, "max": 50, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "16", "area": false, "datalist": [], "default_value": "16", "text_value": "16"}, {"model_class": "BooleanToolParameter", "name": "local_csq", "argument": null, "type": "boolean", "label": "run localized predictions considering only one VCF record at a time", "help": "--local-csq switch off haplotype-aware calling, run localized predictions considering only one VCF record at a time", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "false", "truevalue": "--local-csq", "falsevalue": "", "default_value": "false", "text_value": "false"}, {"model_class": "SelectToolParameter", "name": "phase", "argument": null, "type": "select", "label": "phase", "help": "how to construct haplotypes and how to deal with unphased data", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": true, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": null, "options": [["take GTs as is, create haplotypes regardless of phase (0/1 -> 0|1)", "a", false], ["merge *all* GTs into a single haplotype (0/1 -> 1, 1/2 -> 1)", "m", false], ["require phased GTs, throw an error on unphased het GTs", "r", false], ["create non-reference haplotypes if possible (0/1 -> 1|1, 1/2 -> 1|2)", "R", false], ["skip unphased GTs", "s", false]], "display": null, "multiple": false, "textable": false, "default_value": null, "text_value": "Nothing selected."}, {"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "custom_tag", "argument": null, "type": "text", "label": "use this custom tag to store consequences rather than the default BCSQ tag", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": true, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "", "area": false, "datalist": [], "default_value": "", "text_value": "Empty."}]}, {"model_class": "Section", "name": "sec_restrict", "type": "section", "title": "Restrict to", "help": null, "expanded": false, "inputs": [{"model_class": "Conditional", "name": "regions", "type": "conditional", "cases": [{"model_class": "ConditionalWhen", "value": "__none__", "inputs": []}, {"model_class": "ConditionalWhen", "value": "regions", "inputs": [{"model_class": "Repeat", "name": "regions", "type": "repeat", "title": "Region Filter", "help": null, "default": 1, "min": 1, "max": "__Infinity__", "inputs": [{"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "chrom", "argument": null, "type": "text", "label": "Region chromosome", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "", "area": false, "datalist": []}, {"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "start", "argument": null, "type": "text", "label": "Region start position", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "", "area": false, "datalist": []}, {"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "stop", "argument": null, "type": "text", "label": "Region end position", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "", "area": false, "datalist": []}], "cache": {}}]}, {"model_class": "ConditionalWhen", "value": "regions_file", "inputs": [{"model_class": "DataToolParameter", "name": "regions_file", "argument": null, "type": "data", "label": "Regions File", "help": "restrict to Regions listed in a file", "refresh_on_change": true, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": {"values": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "src": "hda"}]}, "extensions": ["tabular"], "edam": {"edam_formats": ["format_3475"], "edam_data": ["data_0006"]}, "multiple": false, "options": {"hda": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "hid": 11, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: multiz100way (chrX:15,578,261-15,621,068) (as interval)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "955b0e088867ea92", "hid": 10, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: knownGene (genome)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "33d7a2c94fd36485", "hid": 9, "name": "non_ACPs.fasta (as tabular)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "3ba2ccc043967969", "hid": 3, "name": "Extract MAF blocks on data 2 (as interval)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "57c61e66a8a42935", "hid": 2, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: multiz100way (chrX:15,560,138-15,602,945) (as interval)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "1d6404f66ed3d72e", "hid": 1, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: knownGene (genome)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}], "hdca": []}, "default_value": {"values": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "src": "hda"}]}, "text_value": "No dataset."}]}], "test_param": {"model_class": "SelectToolParameter", "name": "regions_src", "argument": null, "type": "select", "label": "Regions", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": true, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "__none__", "options": [["Do not restrict to Regions", "__none__", false], ["Specify one or more Region(s) directly", "regions", false], ["Operate on Regions specified in a history dataset", "regions_file", false]], "display": null, "multiple": false, "textable": false, "text_value": "Do not restrict to Regions"}}, {"model_class": "Conditional", "name": "targets", "type": "conditional", "cases": [{"model_class": "ConditionalWhen", "value": "__none__", "inputs": []}, {"model_class": "ConditionalWhen", "value": "targets", "inputs": [{"model_class": "Repeat", "name": "targets", "type": "repeat", "title": "Target Filter", "help": null, "default": 1, "min": 1, "max": "__Infinity__", "inputs": [{"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "chrom", "argument": null, "type": "text", "label": "Target chromosome", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "", "area": false, "datalist": []}, {"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "start", "argument": null, "type": "text", "label": "Target start position", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "", "area": false, "datalist": []}, {"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "stop", "argument": null, "type": "text", "label": "Target end position", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "", "area": false, "datalist": []}], "cache": {}}]}, {"model_class": "ConditionalWhen", "value": "targets_file", "inputs": [{"model_class": "DataToolParameter", "name": "targets_file", "argument": null, "type": "data", "label": "Targets File", "help": "restrict to Targets listed in a file", "refresh_on_change": true, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": {"values": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "src": "hda"}]}, "extensions": ["tabular"], "edam": {"edam_formats": ["format_3475"], "edam_data": ["data_0006"]}, "multiple": false, "options": {"hda": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "hid": 11, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: multiz100way (chrX:15,578,261-15,621,068) (as interval)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "955b0e088867ea92", "hid": 10, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: knownGene (genome)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "33d7a2c94fd36485", "hid": 9, "name": "non_ACPs.fasta (as tabular)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "3ba2ccc043967969", "hid": 3, "name": "Extract MAF blocks on data 2 (as interval)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "57c61e66a8a42935", "hid": 2, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: multiz100way (chrX:15,560,138-15,602,945) (as interval)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "1d6404f66ed3d72e", "hid": 1, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: knownGene (genome)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}], "hdca": []}, "default_value": {"values": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "src": "hda"}]}, "text_value": "No dataset."}]}], "test_param": {"model_class": "SelectToolParameter", "name": "targets_src", "argument": null, "type": "select", "label": "Targets", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": true, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "__none__", "options": [["Do not restrict to Targets", "__none__", false], ["Specify one or more Target(s) directly", "targets", false], ["Operate on Targets specified in a history dataset", "targets_file", false]], "display": null, "multiple": false, "textable": false, "text_value": "Do not restrict to Targets"}}, {"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "include", "argument": "--include", "type": "text", "label": "Include", "help": "Select sites for which the expression is true", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": true, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": null, "area": false, "datalist": [], "default_value": null, "text_value": "Not available."}, {"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "exclude", "argument": "--exclude", "type": "text", "label": "Exclude", "help": "Exclude sites for which the expression is true", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": true, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": null, "area": false, "datalist": [], "default_value": null, "text_value": "Not available."}]}, {"model_class": "Section", "name": "sec_subset", "type": "section", "title": "Subset Options", "help": null, "expanded": false, "inputs": [{"model_class": "TextToolParameter", "name": "samples", "argument": "--samples", "type": "text", "label": "Samples", "help": "Comma separated list of samples to annotate (or exclude)", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": true, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "", "area": false, "datalist": [], "default_value": "", "text_value": "Empty."}, {"model_class": "BooleanToolParameter", "name": "invert_samples", "argument": null, "type": "boolean", "label": "Invert Samples", "help": "Inverts the query/filtering applied by Samples (adds \\"^\\" prefix to exclude)", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "false", "truevalue": "^", "falsevalue": "", "default_value": "false", "text_value": "false"}, {"model_class": "DataToolParameter", "name": "samples_file", "argument": "--samples_file", "type": "data", "label": "Samples file", "help": "File of samples to include", "refresh_on_change": true, "optional": true, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": null, "extensions": ["tabular"], "edam": {"edam_formats": ["format_3475"], "edam_data": ["data_0006"]}, "multiple": false, "options": {"hda": [{"id": "0b378429c2c91c4f", "hid": 11, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: multiz100way (chrX:15,578,261-15,621,068) (as interval)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "955b0e088867ea92", "hid": 10, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: knownGene (genome)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "33d7a2c94fd36485", "hid": 9, "name": "non_ACPs.fasta (as tabular)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "3ba2ccc043967969", "hid": 3, "name": "Extract MAF blocks on data 2 (as interval)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "57c61e66a8a42935", "hid": 2, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: multiz100way (chrX:15,560,138-15,602,945) (as interval)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}, {"id": "1d6404f66ed3d72e", "hid": 1, "name": "UCSC Main on Human: knownGene (genome)", "tags": [], "src": "hda", "keep": false}], "hdca": []}, "default_value": null, "text_value": "No dataset."}, {"model_class": "BooleanToolParameter", "name": "invert_samples_file", "argument": null, "type": "boolean", "label": "Invert Samples file", "help": "inverts the query/filtering applied by Samples file", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "false", "truevalue": "^", "falsevalue": "", "default_value": "false", "text_value": "false"}]}, {"model_class": "SelectToolParameter", "name": "output_type", "argument": null, "type": "select", "label": "", "help": "", "refresh_on_change": false, "optional": false, "hidden": false, "is_dynamic": false, "value": "b", "options": [["compressed BCF", "b", false], ["uncompressed VCF", "v", false]], "display": null, "multiple": false, "textable": false, "default_value": "b", "text_value": "compressed BCF"}]
```

I am trying to convert this dynamic string to an object using

```
JSON.parse(Kernel_inputs_as_string)
```

It works perfectly for all the cases except a few in which string contains "^" char. It throws an error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^ in JSON at position 13477 error
```

On the other hand, when I copy and save the console.log string as input and trying JSON.parse() it work perfectly as described below.

```
const json = '[{"model_class": "DataToolParameter", "name": "input_file".....}]'
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj[0]);
```

I'm not able to understand why this error is coming and how to solve it for similar cases where the string has "^" char.

Please help me to solve this error.

Thank you

Comment: Are the backslashes really doubled in the JSON, or is that just a console.log artifact? It doesn't work with double backslashes.

Comment: @Barmar if you are talking about this "\\"^\\"" it is present in the string.

Comment: It should just be `\"^\"`

Comment: @Barmar when I checked the python side it's just "(adds "^" prefix to exclude)" there are no backslashes. In this case, why does it's adding backslashes, and how to prevent this.

Comment: A single backslash is needed before a literal `"` in a string. `json.dumps()` should just create `\"`, not `\\"`. So something else must be doubling it, I don't know what.